# JavaScript and HTML Regex not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I have a php page:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        echo $_POST["username"];
        echo $_POST["password"];
        echo $_POST["confirm_password"];
        echo $_POST["email"];
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WordCat Signups</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="signup_validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        Username:<br><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" onkeyup="check_username();"><span id="check_username"></span><br>
        Password:<br><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup="check_password();"><span id="check_password"></span><br>
        Confirm Password:<br><input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onkeyup="check_passwords();"><span id="check_passwords"></span><br>
        Email:<br><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="check_email();"><span id="check_email"></span><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signup"></br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some JavaScript which is meant to check the fields:

```
function check_username(){
    var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
    var pattern = /^[\w[^!\"\#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]]{1,32}$/;
    if(pattern.test(username)){
        document.getElementById("check_username").innerHTML = "Username is valid.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("check_username").innerHTML = "Username is invalid. It should only contain letters, numbers, and underscores, as well as have a maximum of 32 characters.";
    }
}
function check_password(){
    var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
    var pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)([a-zA-z0-9!\"\#$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]{6,})$/;
    if(pattern.test(password)){
        document.getElementById("check_password").innerHTML = "Password is valid.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("check_password").innerHTML = "Password is invalid. It should have at least 6 characters, and at least one number, uppercase, and lowercase character.";
    }
}
function check_passwords(){
    var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
    var confirm_password = document.getElementsByName("confirm_password")[0].value;
    if(password == confirm_password){
        document.getElementById("check_passwords").innerHTML = "Passwords match";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("check_passwords").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match.";
    }
}
```

However, for the JavaScript, the Username and Confirm Password tests are working, but the Password regex is not. When I key in a valid passwords. The regex can be found here [link](https://regex101.com/r/gSVrL9/2) and it is correct for all the tests. However when use my browser the regex fails for valid passwords online!

Comment: The password regex looks alright, just `[A-z]` already matches `\[]^_\``, so you do not have to specify them in the character class.

Comment: Which password are you having an issue with?

Comment: I meant A-Z sorry

Comment: Hmm actually I think its because my localhost on XAMPP is not updating and showing my changes...

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason to use a single regex for a complex condition like yours (other than showing off your regex-fu)...

```
if(
    password.length >= 6 &&  // at least 6 characters
    /[0-9]/.test(password) && // at least one number
    /[a-z]/.test(password) && // at least one lowercase character
    /[A-Z]/.test(password) // at least one lowercase character
) {
    // yay :)
}
```

Comment: I will be using this for a password strength thing though thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone for the trouble. The problem was not my code and instead was XAMPP not updating the code. After I hard refreshed it with Ctrl+F5, it works well. Thanks!